# How to configure IIS7 to view an MVC3 site without interfering with Webforms Production Site?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc

I have a client who is running his ASP.nET 3.5 webforms site on IIS7 under Default Web Site.  I've started development on his MVC3 and have the site files ready for him to review.

How do I setup IIS to serve his MVC3 site as a subdomain(?) so that his productions site continues to function while he can also view progress on the new project?

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS create a new web site which will use a different folder in inetpub.  If using http and not https, then give the new web site binding a host header and create a dns name to match it, so they both are beta.domain.com while production runs www.domain.com.  In IIS make sure new web app has it's own app pool so they don't affect each other, then you should be good to go.